# Reference request for Hermite normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, modules, hermite-normal-form

I need a reference for the result of Hermite Normal Form of a matrix. I would prefer one which states the result in the following form:

the span of $ k $ $ \mathbb{Z} $-linearly independent vectors inside a free $ \mathbb{Z} $-module of rank $ n $, can be "represented" as matrix consisting of an upper triangular $ k \times k $ matrix, above a block of $ ( n - k )  \times  k $ zero matrix.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form

Comment: I need a reference that I can "officially" cite. I know a few books, but I would prefer one in the form that I have given here.